# QGIS difference operation extremely slow

Tags: qgis

I’m running a difference operation in QGIS v3.24.1-Tisler. So far, it has been running for about 26 hours, and is 11% complete. Other geographic operations on these same datasets were complete in a matter of seconds.

Both datasets are in a geopackage, and have had a fix operation performed on them.

Any suggestions as to how to perform a quick difference operation?

Comment: What 'other geographic operations' were quicker? And was it between the same two dataset?

Comment: How many polygons are there in layers?

Comment: Do you have big multipolygons with many parts? Try multipart to singlepart then difference and dissolve (to put them back together)

Comment: Layer 1, 31,051 features; Layer 2, 27,248 features. Previously have performed clip and spatial select operations that completed in seconds. Built a spatial index for both, operation still looks like it wants to last for days.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting a spatial index? For some algorithms in QGIS this makes a *large* difference in the time to completion.

[image: create spatial index algorithm]

Comment: Yes, spatial index doesn’t seem to improve speeds noticeably, though I agree with the suggestion and otherwise am a big fan of spatial indexes for all layers. Frankly, I wonder why it’s not a default option any time QGIS makes a new layer.